# How can I add avatar and hidden field to django idios

Tags: django, pinax

I'm using pinax, and using the idios which is the default profile apps for user profile. However, I don't know how to add my own logic. I know I can customize my own model, but the document seems too naive for me. 
Is there any method to extend idios, for example I want to add a hidden field in module, but I don't know how to change its value when submit the form. Also how can I add gravatar to idios?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since Pinax is just a Django based project so you just inherit from `idios.ProfileBase` model and override AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in settings file with your own profile model

### Your profile with avatar

```
class ProfileWithAvatar(ProfileBase):
    """ Profile model with user avatar """
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/")
    # and add fields whatever you want
```

### settings.py

```
...
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'MyApp.ProfileWithAvatar'
...
```

Enjoy, hope this will help for you.

Sultan,

Thanks